# How to have dynamic Nunit TestCaseSource in C#?

Tags: c#, nunit

What I'd like to do is exactly the first example from this page but...

http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5

with value that I can change

```
    static object[] DivideCases =
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < qtyCmd(); i++)
        {
            new object[] { getCmd[i] },
        }
    };
```

qtyCmd is just a static method which return a number
getCmd read a line (index sent as parameter) in a text file

where the arrays command. I know about Data-Driven Unit Test, but I was asked to do not use it. To be more specific, I am asked to do so with `[TestCase]`

Comment: I really don't see any problems...for example if you have a static function `GetCommandFromFile` in place of `command[i]` it would work...cannot see the problem that you are facing.

Comment: I get unexpected symbol for in the static object declaration... maybe it's my syntax?

Comment: Could you post a little more code? I think that your mistake is really simple...your `command`, `argument` and `argument2` fields are not static. You cannot use class instance fields in a static method...

Comment: One hint, use meaningful name. If the functions qtyCmd() and getCmd() are static...it should work. However, if your getCmd is returning an array, you should directly return it and not use `new object[] { getCmd...`.

Comment: thx a lot. They are both static and getCmd return a string. May I ask how the name could be more meaningful? Should I specify in the name the return value?
However at compilations it says unexpected for.

Comment: You are welcome. Related to the names, maybe `GetCommandQuantity`and `GetCommand`...start by the right way, don't be lazy :), you have code completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn `DivideCases` into a method:

```
private object[] DivideCases() {
    var amountOfSamples = qtyCmd();
    var result = new object[amountOfSamples];

    for (var i = 0; i < amountOfSamples; i++) {
        result[i] = new object[] {getCmd[i]};
    }

    return result;
}
```

And then use it with `TestCaseSource`:

```
[Test, TestCaseSource("DivideCases")]
public void TestMethod(object[] samples) {
    // Your test here.
}
```

Comment: Warning: In NUnit 3.0, TestCaseSource must now point to a static method or use n class that implements IEnumerable. I have a large number of tests that build the TestCaseSource dynamically from constructor arguments and there is no way to do that in NUnit 3.0

Comment: @Novaterata, I am having same probelm in 3.0, any workaround?
I use `List<dynamic>` for a function parameter.

Comment: @Umar as I said you must use a static method and not a ctor. https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute